# Python deleting lines with characters

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am looking for the best way to delete all lines from a file that contains characters.

For example, from below, only User1, User2, User3 and User 4 would exist after processing. Notice User 4 has a space.

```
5!pY
"TmL
c]+y?"
|)}?E
\e2g%
User1
User2
User3
User 4
11-01-05
[GO-B
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Are only spaces allowed between User and 4. Also, what about the case of `User3 foo bar baz`? Should foo bar baz be stripped out or left in as part of the line?

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "characters"? Do you mean "any character that isn't a letter, number, or space"?

Answer (score 2):

If you can make sure that you are going to have a *User* word, you can use that to identify 'valid' text: you could go with regular expressions that look for the string "User" followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by one or more digits:

```
>>> import re
>>> line='5!pY "TmL c]+y?" |)}?E \e2g% User1 User2 User3 User 4 11-01-05 [GO-B'
>>> regex=re.compile("User\s*\d+")
>>> regex.findall(line)
['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User 4']
```

Otherwise, you'll need to edit the question and provide a bit more information.

Comment: Hi Folks, apologies for the poor description. I was looking to delete lines which contained anything other than letters, numbers or spaces. I really appreciate the replies and am all set. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean remove all lines that contain characters that are not letters, digits, or space then this should do the trick.

```
import string

data = """5!pY
TmL
c]+y?"
|)}?E
\e2g%
User1
User2
User3
User 4
11-01-05
[GO-B"""

allowed = string.letters + string.digits + ' '

clean_data = [item for item in data.split('\n') if set(item).issubset(allowed)]
print clean_data #  ['TmL', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User 4']
```

Comment: Hi Folks, apologies for the poor description. I was looking to delete lines which contained anything other than letters, numbers or spaces. I really appreciate the replies and am all set. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of those lines contain characters, so I  will assume you mean punctuation and spaces?

```
import sys,string
xChars = string.punctuation + " "
for x in sys.stdin:
        for c in x. strip():
                if c in xChars:
                        break
        else:
                print x.strip()
```

Running this script on the file "deleteme" containing your example data:

```
> cat deleteme | python dellines.py 
User1
User2
User3
```

Comment: Hi Folks, apologies for the poor description. I was looking to delete lines which contained anything other than letters, numbers or spaces. I really appreciate the replies and am all set. Thanks very much.